# Nested EJS tags

Tags: ejs

I have a database full of game logs that I want to list out.  I don't have a problem listing out the games, but I would like to be able to change how many games to list on the page.  I set this up in a form to input a number to choose how many game logs to display.   I can get the correct info in a console.log, but it is not working on the ejs aspect.

I am trying to do this below, but the <%= %> tags being nested within the <% %> tags seems to be problematic:

```
<% games.slice(<%= listLength %>).reverse().forEach(function(game, index){ %>
```

Any ideas on how to access listLength?

I tried the code below based on another answer on stackoverflow, but the listLength is still not being recorgnized.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th># of Players</th>
            <th>Winner</th>
            <th>Winning Score</th>
            <th>Losing Score</th>
            <th>Other Details</th>
        </tr>

        <% games.slice(listLength).reverse().forEach(function(game, index){ %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= index + 1 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= game.date.toDateString() %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= game.name %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= game.numOfPlayers %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= game.winner %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= game.winningScore %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= game.losingScore %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= game.otherDetails %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>

    </table>
```

All of the game info is being displayed properly, but the listLength[0].listLength is still not being accepted in the code to change the length of the list.

Comment: Seems to work in my (very) simple demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hoy9x4bj/. Can you provide more code? And a minimal example? (of how you call the ejs function, too)

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle.  It didn't have the <%= %> tags nested directly between (on same line) the <% %> tags.     I updated the question above with more code.   I can access the listLength data in a console.log, but it still isn't being recognized through the ejs tags.

Comment: When I use the "listLength" without the <%= %> tags,  it isn't throwing an error or anything anymore, but it isn't changing the list length.  If I hardcode a number where 'listLength' is, the list displays only the amount of game logs as the number given.    So the real question may be, is my listLength variable (which is a Number in the database) not being recognized as  Number on the ejs side.

Comment: I ran typeof in the ejs tag, and it is a Number.   The list length is just not changing based on the listLength ejs variable.    Even more frustrating, I used a different ejs variable that is a number as well and tested it in the same spot, and it did actually change the list length respectively.

Comment: Still seems to work for me. https://jsfiddle.net/g17c3m4k/. Can you give a jsfiddle or code snippet where it doesn't work? I'm thinking it might be something with how you pass variables to the ejs.render function. Are you using express, node, or just js in the browser?

Comment: Not sure I can duplicate it in a jsfiddle, but I'll look and see if I can.     when I pass listLength anywhere on the page using <%= %> tags, the variable is shown correctly.   The slice method is just not responding to it for some reason.   I am fairly new to ejs and displaying data from database.   To avoid getting listLength from the db, what would be a good way to change listLength on the client-side?

Comment: Just to see, can you put `<%= listLength %>` in your ejs (before the loop)? What does that show?

Comment: It shows 12, which is what I have it set as in the database initially.   I ran typeof and it is a  Number.  But it still does nothing in the slice method.  It just ignores it and displayed every gamelog in the database.

Comment: That's odd. I don't know if it works, but try using `parseInt(listLength)`

Comment: I ended up fixing the overall goal by using limit() on the get request.  This probably should have been what I did from the get-go, but I think during initial development I was led to the slice method on the front-end for some reason.     For the specific issue we have been battling here, I did try the parseInt() and nothing happened.  I never could get it to recognize anything other than a hard coded number within the slice method.  Thank you for your time and help.  I appreciate it.